# Variable from url in django base template file

Tags: python, html, css, django

I would like to use on my django base template file variable that will be depends on my part of url adress.

for an instance, these are my urls:
http://localhost:8000/name1/start
http://localhost:8000/name2/start

and in base html file I'd like to write it between h1 tags:

> ## {{ name }}

and depending on the url, I should see

> ## name1
>
> ## name2

important information, I don't like to create a block for it, because that informaton will be on each page so I don't want to write the same block in each views/ template

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a custom context processor which will parse the URL and append the name bit to the context. Then it will be available in all your views. You may want to look at one of the inbuilt Django ones for examples. Here's a link to docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pattern in your url.py as bellow:

`r'^(?P<name>\w+)/start', views.your_view),`

and define your_view as:

```
def your_view(request, name):
   return render(request, 'your_template', {
      'name': name,
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

url will look like

```
url(r'^anyname/(?P<query>.+)/$', views.viewToShow,name="Filter")
```

and view.py will look like

```
def viewToShow(request,query):

   print(query)#this query contains that url value
```